# Solr 3.4 and Httpclient 4

Tags: java, configuration, solr, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is it possible to configure solrj server 3.4 with DefaultHttpClient (httpclient-4.x)?

**Updated**

Where can i download solrj client library based on httpclient-4.x?

i can't build it from solr svn trunk repository( they are still using httpclient-3.x)

Comment: what do you mean by configure ?

Comment: just configure solr server to use already existent DefaultHttpClient instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using existing httpclient with Solr server e.g.

```
DefaultHttpClient hhtpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
SolrServer solrSvr = net CommonsHttpSolrServer(url, hhtpclient);
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
QueryResponse res = solrSvr.query(query);
SolrDocumentList results = res.getResults();
```

Comment: how can i inject existent DefaultHttpClient instance into org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer?

Comment: you can pass the instance of http client to the solr server constructor, which would then be used. Updated answer with an example.

Comment: this is not possible because apache-solr-solrj-3.4.0.jar is based on httpclient 3 version, not 4.

Comment: ohk ... yup ... 3.4 still uses 3. The trunk may have been upgraded. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2727.

Comment: ok, thanks. HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8"); this string too important for me:)

Comment: i hope the new solrj release(with version of httpclient 4) will be available soon:)

Comment: we are waiting for 4.x for an year now and working on a nightly build. Hoping for the same :)